# Dynamic Key Value Pair in DataWeave

Tags: mule, dataweave

DataWeave doesn't like what I'm trying to do with it, and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if it is a limitation of DataWeave that isn't possible.

Here's the scenario: I'm querying Salesforce and getting two values back: lets call them X and Y.

Here's the return I want `[{X:Y}, {X2:Y2}, {X3:Y3}, ...]` however, using DataWeave it doesnt seem possible to get a key value pair like that, instead, it only seems possible to specifically set the Key for each value in the script like so: `[{Value_X: X, Value_Y: Y}, {Value_X: X2, Value_Y: Y2}, ...]`

Here is my current DataWeave script that works, but gives me the second result:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---

payload map {
    Value_X: $.X,
    Value_Y: $.Y
}
```

And here's the DataWeave script that I wish worked, but doesn't

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---

payload map {
    $.X: $.Y
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order for your Dataweave code to work properly, you need to surround the variable you want to use as a key with parentheses:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---

payload map {
    ($.X): $.Y
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Can you try what is in the image below?

[image]

Comment: I think you may be on the right track, and I think this would work for a normal input, but Salesforce returns a ConsumerIterator, and DataWeave throws this exception `1. Cannot coerce a :iterator to a :object (com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.coercion.exception.UnsupportedTypeCoercionExc
eption)`

Answer (score 0):

Data Weave supports conditional key value pairs.

Look at this documentation 
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-types#conditional-elements-2

Comment: link is (now) broken, oonly returns page not found.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have column names separate from column values.

```
<results>
  <meta-data>
    <column-label>X1</column-label>
    <column-label>X2</column-label>
  </meta-data>
  <data>
    <column-value>Y1</column-value>
    <column-value>Y2</column-value>
  </data>
</results>
```

The following dwl layout worked:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
using (y= payload.results)
y.data map using (x= payload.results.meta-data[$$]) {
  (x): $
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Dynamic key:value pair mapping mapobject is the only way.

Please read below link for more information related to mapobject

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-operators#map-object

Answer (score -2):

It seems like DataWeave is unable to do this from my experiments. I did get it to work using a Python scripting transformer. Here is the XML that will do this translation properly:

```
<scripting:transformer doc:name="Python">
<scripting:script engine="jython">
<![CDATA[
    map = {}
    while (payload.hasNext()):
        next = payload.next()
        map[next['X']] = next['Y']
    result = map
]]>
</scripting:script>
</scripting:transformer>
```

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way is `(payload01.Notification.dynamicProperties map (payload02, indexofPayload02) -> { (payload02.name) : payload02.value })`